# Perl Regexes - Replacing certain instances of matches

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to replace text in a source file much like how 
the C preprocessor works. My approach is to parse 
constants and their values and populate a hash array with 
them. My problem is as follows:

In the source file, I have:

```
#define CONSTANT 10
#define CONSTANT_PLUS_ONE CONSTANT + 1
```

I use `/^#define\s+(\w.*)\s+.*($key).*/` to match the second
line, but when I replace with `s/$2/$defines{$key}/`, both
instances of CONSTANT are replaced, i.e.

```
#define CONSTANT 10
#define 10_PLUS_ONE 10 + 1
```

I'm something of a Perl novice, so I'm hoping someone can
point me in the right direction, or if I've made a blatantly
stupid mistake.

Comment: Are you using /g in your replace regex, but omitting it in your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try specifying word boundaries:

```
s/\b$2\b/$defines{$key}/g;
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. I had tried this already and some how messed it up.
Thank you dreeves, I think I can sleep now!

Answer (score 3):

`\w.*` will match a word character, and then any number of any character, which is not what you want -- you need to bind to word endings, or at least ensure that every character in the match is a word character, e.g. `\w+`. So try this:

```
/^#define\s+(\w+)\s+($key).*/
```

See the full specification of special characters and match types at [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: This is probably more robust but the problem Conor had was something different, I think.

Comment: I see what you're saying, Ether. That's a good point. I'll amend this too. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

You can also just run your code through the C preprocessor.  Hand it in as STDIN so the compiler doesn't try to get smart and read too much into the file extension.

```
cc -E - < <file> > <newfile>
```

And if this is Perl source code you're doing it to, it already has constants.  And yes, you get all the performance benefit of inlining.

```
use constant PI => 3.14;
use constant CAKE => PI + 1.2345;
```